# AndEngine - Stop all Sound and Music runtime - Change AudioOptions of Engine

Tags: android, audio, andengine

I'm trying to create Settings for game which allows user to save whether u need sound or not (CheckBox).

when user unchecks it, i want to disable all further sounds.

This is what i'm doing

```
// Create Dialog
final SexyAlertDialog dialog = new SexyAlertDialog(mActivity,R.layout.settings,R.style.SettingDialog,false);

// Find CheckBox
final CheckBox isSoundEnabled = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.isSoundEnabled);

// Check SharedPreferences to get isSoundEnabled value
if(mSettingPreferences.getBoolean("isSoundEnabled", false)){
    isSoundEnabled.setChecked(true);
}else{
    isSoundEnabled.setChecked(false);
}

// OnCheckedChangeListener on Checkbox in AlertDialog
isSoundEnabled.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
            mSettingEditor.putBoolean("isSoundEnabled", true);
            mSettingEditor.commit();

            // Enable Music and Sound
            mActivity.getEngine().getEngineOptions().getAudioOptions().setNeedsSound(true);
            mActivity.getEngine().getEngineOptions().getAudioOptions().setNeedsMusic(true);

            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Audio Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            mSettingEditor.putBoolean("isSoundEnabled", false);
            mSettingEditor.commit();

            // Disable Music and Sound
            mActivity.getEngine().getEngineOptions().getAudioOptions().setNeedsSound(false);
            mActivity.getEngine().getEngineOptions().getAudioOptions().setNeedsMusic(false);

            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Audio Disabled  !! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});

    dialog.show();
```

Even after  doing

```
mActivity.getEngine().getEngineOptions().getAudioOptions().setNeedsSound(false);
mActivity.getEngine().getEngineOptions().getAudioOptions().setNeedsMusic(false);
```

Sound still plays.
How can i disable every sound ?

Or, Do i have to do it like:

```
if(mSettingPreferences.getBoolean("isSoundEnabled", false)){
     pMySound.play();
}
```

For every sound in my app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could iterate over all of your `Music` and `Sound` objects and call `stop()`, `pause()` or `setVolume(0,0)` on them.

You could also try muting all sounds by setting the master volume to 0:

```
mActivity.getEngine().getMusicManager().setMasterVolume(0);
mActivity.getEngine().getSoundManager().setMasterVolume(0);
```

Comment: Worked !! :D
to enable sound and music again i should set setMasterVolume(1);
Right?

Comment: I would guess that the maximum is 1.0 since it's a float, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Note that if you want to reduce the power consumption you'd be better of pausing/stopping all music/sounds rather than just setting the volume to 0.

Answer (score 3):

As stated by Michael, you can pause the sound instead of setting volume to zero.

```
mActivity.getEngine().getSoundManager().onPause();
```

This will stop all sounds. **No need to iterate over every sound and pause each one**.
To resume:

```
mActivity.getEngine().getSoundManager().onResume();
```

Comment: Where did you find this function in  [SoundManager class?](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/audio/sound/SoundManager.java)

Comment: It was addded 10 months ago https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2-AnchorCenter/src/org/andengine/audio/sound/SoundManager.java. Update your andengine.

Comment: Your link took me to GLES2. The latest andengine is GLES2-AnchorCenter. https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2-AnchorCenter/src/org/andengine/audio/sound/SoundManager.java Change the branch and download. The functions weren't there in AnchorCenter  either but was added 10 months ago.

Comment: how does this work on getMusicManager(). there is no onPause() and onResume()